# I have two input field in html and I am thinking how can i get value of first inputted field into the next inputted field automatically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have two input field in html and I am thinking how  can i get value of first inputted field into the next inputted field automatically. I am unable to do this in php. if anybody can help me with this . I will be very helpful to you. I think ajax may be used to do this. but i am unable to do this.

```
    <input type="number" name="firstnumber"><br>
<input type="number" name="secondnumber">
```

Second input type may be different if you think it is wrong. as per your guide I will change it. but what I am trying to make is  there should be two input type field where in first field I can input any number only and after entering any number in first field I will be able to see some value in second input field without clicking on any submit button means value in second input field will come automatically after entering into first field which cannot be edited.

To make it easier to understand I am giving here one example. Kindly solve this and guide me in this so that I can learn and can code myself in a better way.

Suppose I am entering 500 in first input field then second input field should display result value after decreasing 10% of first inputted field.

Comment: You need to post your code, or what you have tried. Right now there is 100 different ways you can go about this in any number of languages. PICK ONE!

Comment: I need help in php and ajax

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/59b6juq0/

Comment: this time i have  posted code also . thanks waiting for your guide and kind help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have an input field where you enter the field like so:

```
<input type="text" id="i_am_lazy" />
```

You need a somewhere to display it:

```
<div id="atleast_try"></div>
```

You can trigger a function on change for the input box like so:

```
$("#i_am_lazy").change(function(){
    var number_i_want_to_work_with = parseInt($(this).val());
    $("#atleast_try").text(number_i_want_to_work_with + 5); // Do whatever calculation you need to do
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am new to php. so kindly give a little more explanation. and give example with any no. now i want if any one enter 400 in one field then it will automatically deduct 0.5% from first value and after deducted show in second field in php and ajax . a  little more explanation i need thanks for your reply

Comment: It is not php, it is Jquery, and that is all you need. Copy and paste that and change the calculation bit to what you need.

Comment: hello brother. good news . your code worked

Comment: how i can keep the result value in any input field so that i can send it to database and can session if rquired

Comment: I suggest creating a new question. I can help you but not in this comment box. You can either use a form submission using a hidden field in a form or use AJAX to send your data to a php function.